# Parameter after url is not passed to called function when Parameter contains : or \

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

I am passing keyword inputed by user to 
function search_result($input) 
in cakephp fron Javascript
like this [www.example.com/search_result/input](http://www.example.com/search_result/input) from Javascript
where input is from user
It gives an error when input contains `:` as `no arguments found for search_result`.  It working fine for other inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to encode the search term before passing it to PHP from Javascript (which I assume means you're using AJAX).

You can do this by using:`encodeURIComponent`:

```
encodeURIComponent(term);
```

Comment: encodeURIComponent(term) or escape(term) is working for other characters except ":"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to URI encoding, the problem is that `:` is used to separate cake parameters, so when you have it in your search query, cake thinks it's a param.

But, there is a fix in [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes), apparently, you can use the "trailing star syntax":

```
Router::connect(
    '/search_result/**', // notice two stars instead of one
    array('controller' => 'search', 'action' => 'search_result')
);
```

This should pass **everything** after the `/search_result/` as a single param.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @NadeemAnsari: Can you show us your routes file? This should work unless it's overriden by some other route.

Comment: No ,there is no other route with this name or no other route specified above this overriding it.

Comment: @NadeemAnsari: have you tried testing this with the cake console shell? Are your controller and action called `search` and `search_result`?